# NodeMCU and relay with VIN power

Tags: nodemcu, relay, wires

Have read a lot of different things online, and I just ain't sure yet.
I'm trying to hook up a NodeMCU to control some relays. And want to power the NodeMCU by the VIN pin.
Anyone know if this setup is possible?
Or should I do it in another way? 
[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to use the JDVCC at all when I use this setup?
Maybe I can keep the jumper on VCC/JDVCC and only connect to the VCC on the relay?

Comment: you would use JDVCC with separate power supply for relay coils. then you would not connect the grounds. main reason would be to prevent EMI from relays switching

Comment: So what you are saying is that, for my setup, I don't need to use JDVCC?

Comment: I see. For my setup, I will only be using max 2-3 relay at the time

Comment: 24VAC to control some irrigation valves

Comment: it should, but you could also be just out of range of the 5v hi/lo. You can fix that with a level shifter, or, feed the esp32 3.6v instead of 3.3v (still in spec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me, I don't see any issues, assuming the PSU has sufficient 'grunt' to power both, and most will have.

Comment: I'm using a 24VAC to 5VDC 3A converter as the PSU supply

Comment: Plenty of surplus power there, you shouldn't have any issues